# Should I always test the types of each function's parameters?

Tags: python, validation, types

I have a function which has a parameter `intTup`. That function is being called by a user and hence the input might be erroneous, so I want to validate it.

In particular, `intTup` must :

- be a tuple
- be of length 3
- contain only ints

So, as soon as the function is executed, those properties are checked :

```
def myFunc(intTup)
    if type(intTup) is not tuple:
        print("intTup       = ", intTup)
        print("type(intTup) = ", type(intTup))
        raise Exception('In parameter intTup : should be a tuple of float')
    elif (len(h) != 3) :
        print("intTup      = ", intTup)
        print("len(intTup) = ", len(intTup))
        raise Exception('In parameter intTup : should contain three atoms')
    elif [int]*len(intTup) == map(type,intTup):
        print("intTup       = ", intTup)
        print("type(intTup) = ", map(type,intTup))
        raise Exception('In parameter h : all atoms should be ints')
    # Some actual code follow these tests
```

Of course that type of checks is frequently encountered : anytime a function admits a parameter of type tuple containing n values of type t a similar check must be run. Hence, should I define a function `checkTuple(tupleToTest, shouldBeLen, shouldBeType)` to automate these checks ? Or should I leave how it is ? How do you proceed in your scripts ?

Comment: Would you like to use `if type(intTup) is not tuple:` instead `if not type(intTup) is tuple:`?

Comment: Why stand in the way of ducktyping? let the users send a list or other sequences to your function if so they like :)

Comment: @KevinGuan indeed, that would be better !

Comment: @ReblochonMasque the example above is a dummy example. In one real case example, the user must enter the x-, y- and z-spacing between two grid nodes. It doesn't make any sense to allow something else than a tuple containing three ints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  In Python you use "duck type": if something walks like a duck, quacks like a duck, and swims like a duck, it is identified with a duck.

In other words, with Python, we believe that *it is what you do that defines what you are*.

Which means you should rely on the property of an object, rather than its type.  In your case, you just use the input the way a "3-tuple containing `int`s" is meant to be used, and handle exceptions.

See also: [`isinstance` considered harmful](https://web.archive.org/web/20130723051433/http://www.canonical.org/~kragen/isinstance/).

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you should consider EAFP.

> Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission. This common Python coding style assumes the existence of valid keys or attributes and catches exceptions if the assumption proves false. This clean and fast style is characterized by the presence of many try and except statements. The technique contrasts with the LBYL style common to many other languages such as C.

[docs](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp)

Try to process user input and if it fails for whatever reason, raise an exception. This is not how would you normally do it in most of other languages where emphasis is on prevention of error, but for python it is common to use EAFP principle.

In other words, do not validate.

Answer (score 1):

What's the point of using a language without static type checking if you are going to implement runtime type checking anyway? The answer to your question is that: no; you should not always check the parameter constraints. If you want to have that kind of control there are better tools for the job. There are cases where you may want to type check, such as when accepting input from users or outside processes, but you do not want to *always* do it.

Answer (score 1):

If you really (really?) must break ducktyping, you could assert the validity of the params as follows:

```
def myFunc(intTup):
    """intTup is a tuple of size 3"""
    assert(isinstance(intTup, tuple)), "not a tuple"
    assert(len(intTup) == 3), "not length 3"
```

Easier to Ask Forgiveness than Permission :)

You could take a look at the [warnings module](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/warnings.html).

Comment: What is the purpose of assert in a try block?

Comment: Sorry @ReblochonMasque at first I did not understand the point of your question in your initial comment… I had to read docs about EAFP first… (noob programmer here !)

Answer (score 0):

You can make a decorator to check if

```
     def validate(func):
         def f(*args, **kwargs): 
             if args[0] is not tuple or len(args[0])! =3:
                 raise Exception("invalid parameter") 
             return func(*args, **kwargs) 
         return f
```